# How can I call a function in a class using stdclass in codeigniter

Tags: function, codeigniter, class, object, stdclass

I am newbie in CodeIgniter. I have a question related to functions in controller. Index function in the controller is like below.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $data                   = new stdClass;
        $data->words            = "Apple";
        $data->shuffled_words   = str_shuffle("Apple");

        $this->load->view('t/header');
        $this->load->view('projects/game', $data);
        $this->load->view('t/footer');
    }
```

But I have written index function in two function. There is something wrong didn't worked.

```
        public function index()
        {
            $this->shuffle();
            $this->load->view('t/header');
            $this->load->view('projects/game', $data);
            $this->load->view('t/footer');
        }

        public function shuffle()
        {
             $data                  = new stdClass;
             $data->words           = "Apple";
             $data->shuffled_words  = str_shuffle("Apple");
        }
```

Could you help me about the problem?

Comment: you can call same class functions using $this. I guess you have got error for $data variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$data is not avail able inside index function. 
Use this way

```
 public function index()
    {
        $data=$this->shuffle();//make $data available here
        $this->load->view('t/header');
        $this->load->view('projects/game', $data);
        $this->load->view('t/footer');
    }

    public function shuffle()
    {
         $data                  = new stdClass;
         $data->words           = "Apple";
         $data->shuffled_words  = str_shuffle("Apple");
         return $data;//return the values
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a vary quick solution. I hope it will help you.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $data = $this->shuffle();
        $this->load->view('t/header');
        $this->load->view('projects/game', $data);
        $this->load->view('t/footer');
    }

    public function shuffle()
    {
         $data                  = new stdClass;
         $data->words           = "Apple";
         $data->shuffled_words  = str_shuffle("Apple");

         return $data;
    }
```